# How to install 64-bit Python on Solaris?

Tags: python, solaris

I am trying to install Python 2.6 on [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)) by building the source on Solaris machine. I installed one this way and it appears that it is 32-bit. I downloaded some source tar ball as Linux or Unix for this purpose. Everything works well but I need 64-bit Python.

I looked up the Python download site and there is no separate installation for a 64-bit Python. 
That makes me think that there must be some option while running configure and/or install commands to install Python. I tried reading README.txt of the installation but could not find any info. I am very new to installations on "Unix" like systems.

How can I install 64-bit Python on Solaris?

Comment: Have you tried: https://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

It's currently an [acknowledged bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1306248) that Solaris 64-bit support is suboptimal, but that bug report looks to contain some flags that you might want to use. See also [this mailing list posting](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/540079/).

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest seeing if you can get away with the 32 bit version of Python.  If your new to compiling stuff on Solaris, this will save you *many* headaches.  However, it is possible, and I do have a working 64 bit version of Python.  I'm using *cc: Sun C 5.8 2005/10/13* to compile.  Additionally, I've already compiled 64-bit version of readline and ncurses.

My configure line looks like this:

```
../Python-2.6.1/configure CCSHARED="-KPIC" LDSHARED="cc -xarch=generic64 -G -KPIC" LDFLAGS="-xarch=generic64 -L/opt/tools/lib -R/opt/tools/lib -L/opt/tools/ssl/lib -ltermcap -lz -R $ORIGIN/../lib" CC="cc" CPP="cc -xarch=generic64 -E -I/opt/tools/include -I/opt/tools/include/ncurses -I/opt/tools/include/readline" BASECFLAGS="-xarch=generic64 -I/opt/tools/include -I/opt/tools/include/ncurses" OPT="-xO5" CFLAGS="-xarch=generic64 -I/opt/tools/include -I/opt/tools/include/ncurses -I/opt/tools/include/readline" CXX="CC -xarch=generic64 -I/opt/tools/include -I/opt/tools/include/ncurses"  --prefix=/opt/tools/python-2.6.1 --enable-64-bit --without-gcc --disable-ipv6 --with-ssl=openssl --with-ncurses --with-readline
```

Additionally, I modified these two lines in Modules/Setup.local to include the required locations:

```
readline readline.c -I/opt/tools/include/readline -L/opt/tools/lib -lreadline -ltermcap
_ssl _ssl.c -I/opt/tools/ssl/include -L/opt/tools/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Now, just pray you don't need to compile in some Sybase bindings or some other 64-bit libraries.

Comment: Is there a huge performance difference running the 64-bit version if you're not dealing with large data?